# LTE modem has 1 connection avalible

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, usb-modem, modem

Trying to set up LTE internet connection via quectel USB modem. I've tried configuring netplan with 2 different plans. the sim is unlocked so no pin is necessary

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  modems:
    cdc-wdm0:
      auto-config: true
      # dhcp4: yes
      # dhcp6: no
```

One was with auto-config:true. In this configuration nmcli modem is in state of connecting(prepare).

```
wlan0          wifi      connected             netplan-wlan0
eth0           ethernet  connected             netplan-eth0              
docker0        bridge    connected             docker0                   
cdc-wdm0       gsm       connecting (prepare)  netplan-cdc-wdm0          
p2p-dev-wlan0  wifi-p2p  disconnected          --
```

Second with dhcp4 and dhcp6. In this configuration nmcli modem is disconnected with one connection avalible.

```
cdc-wdm0: disconnected
        "cdc-wdm0"
        1 connection available
        gsm (option, qmi_wwan), hw
```

mmcli -m -L status is enabled, and bearer is also avalible on type ipv4v6

I'm not sure if I should focus on the autocofing or dhcp4/6 or how to proceed from this point as I'm new to networking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no PIN to insert you could try the following configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  modems:
    cdc-wdm0:
      apn: insert.your.apn.here
      dhcp4: true
      #if user and password are needed:
      #username: [your-username]
      #password: [your-password]
```

then reload netplan:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```